# JQuery ui in not working with mfc htmldialog?

Tags: javascript, c++, jquery-ui, visual-studio-2013, mfc

This code perfect work with asp.net c#. I am using this code but not working with mfc htmldialog. Error is Object does't support property or method tabs.

```
  <HEAD>
        <title></title>
        <link href="jquery-ui-1.8.8/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.8/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.8/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.8/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.8/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="jquery-ui-1.8.8/demos/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function ($) {
                // rely on $ within safety of "bodyguard" function
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#tabs").tabs();
                });

            })(jQuery);


        </script>

    </HEAD>
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please remove '$' before alert. If still doesnot work, try to using `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`. If it work, it means you cannot import library.

Comment: After using this 1 error is remove about jquery. But another error $alert is null or undefined?

Comment: yup, try change '$alert' to 'alert'

Comment: That is worked. Now i want to use  $("#tabs").tabs();. When i use this the error is Object does't support property or method tabs?

Comment: try to import  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: this work  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>; But the tab is not arrange?

Comment: Root cause is your imported library, you use wrong path. You can check by this way, right mouse in your page and you can see your link which I imported. Click links, if 404 --> path is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79607/discussion-between-muhammad-raza-and-nhan-nguyn).